# Start weblogic weblogic12.2.1.4.0 causes exceptions

Tags: jar, dependencies, weblogic

I imported my maven project then I started my project on my weblogic server but it gives

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: weblogic.i18n.logging.CatalogMessage.getLocalizerResourceName()
```

I checked my jar file and I saw it does not contains CatalogMessage class.Do you have any idea how to fix that problem.

My pom fies contains weblogic 10.3.2.0 jar but it does not contains necessary class files

My full error message :

```
The WebLogic Server encountered a critical failure
Reason:weblogic.common.internal.VersionInfo.initialize(ZLjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;IIII)V
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: weblogic.i18n.logging.CatalogMessage.getLocalizerResourceName()Ljava/lang/String;
at weblogic.logging.MessageLogger.log(MessageLogger.java:68)
at weblogic.logging.MessageLogger.log(MessageLogger.java:114)
at weblogic.logging.WLMessageLogger.log(WLMessageLogger.java:52)
at weblogic.kernel.T3SrvrLogger.logServerStateChange(T3SrvrLogger.java:2284)
at weblogic.t3.srvr.T3Srvr.setState(T3Srvr.java:190)
at weblogic.t3.srvr.T3Srvr.run(T3Srvr.java:458)
at weblogic.Server.main(Server.java:67)
```

I cannot understand why project contains weblogic 10.3.2.0 jar?I use weblogic 12.2.1.4.0 .

My pom file is :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.myRepo.reporter-application.project</groupId>
        <artifactId>weblogic</artifactId>
        <version>10.3.2.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Does your server start when the application is not deployed ?
This class belongs to WebLogic.
Can you provide the complete error message including the stack trace. Thx

Comment: I cannot start weblogic server so I cannot deploy my application.

Comment: Can you provide the complete error message including the stack trace. Thx

Comment: I updated my question with complete error message

Comment: your pom file use 10.3.2 : 
 <version>10.3.2.0</version>
How do you start your server ? Node Manager ? WLST ? Shell script ?

Comment: I start my project from run configuration.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234856/discussion-between-tom-and-emmanuel-collin).